# Get books with 2 or more authors in SQL

Tags: sql, join, select, count

So I've a problem where I want to get books which have more than two authors. Im new at T-SQL so, I dont get it so well yet..

My tables looks like this

Book table:

```
     BOOK
---------------
book_id | title
---------------
   1    |   A
   2    |   B
```

Author table:

```
     AUTHOR
----------------
author_id | name
----------------
     1    | Nick
     2    | Clem
     3    | John
```

Book-Author table:

```
  BOOK_AUTHOR
--------------------
book_id |  author_id
--------------------
   1    |     1
   1    |     2
   2    |     3
```

So, as you are seeing, the expected output I want is this:

```
 Author_id |  title  |       author_name
------------------------------------------
    1    |    A    | Nick
    2    |    A    | Clem
```

Here is the SQL Query Im executing:

```
SELECT a.Id, a.name, b.title, count(ba.idBook)
FROM BookAuthors as ba
JOIN Author as a
ON ba.IdAuthor = a.Id
JOIN book as b
ON ba.idBook = b.id
GROUP BY a.Id, a.name, b.title
HAVING count(ba.idBook) > 1
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: Change the number in your `HAVING` clause. `> 0` means that one author meets the criteria. You want more than one.

Comment: Edited: I've set it to > 1 but the output is blank

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a subquery, which will find all book ids which have more than two authors:

```
SELECT c.book_id
  FROM book_author c
  GROUP BY c.book_id
  HAVING count(c.book_id) >= 2
```

... and then use this in your main query, to get all authors & books from your joined tables whos book id appears in the subquery:

```
SELECT ba.author_id, a.name AS author_name, b.title
FROM 
    book_author ba JOIN book b ON ba.book_id = b.book_id
    JOIN author a ON ba.author_id = a.author_id
WHERE
    b.book_id IN (SELECT c.book_id
                    FROM book_author c
                    GROUP BY c.book_id
                    HAVING count(c.book_id) >= 2);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just a.author_name it should be a.name and b.book_title should be b.title according to tables.

Comment: @IsaAtaseven thanks for pointing that out. I believe it should be fixed now

Answer (score 0):

You want *books* with more than two authors.  Your query is close, but you want to exclude the specific author information:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.title, COUNT(*) as num_authors
FROM BookAuthors ba JOIN
     book b
     ON ba.idBook = b.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

The question does not seem to be asking you to list the authors.  If so, a convenient method would be `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.title, COUNT(*) as num_authors,
       STRING_AGG(author_name, ', ') as authors
FROM BookAuthors ba JOIN
     book b
     ON ba.idBook = b.id
GROUP BY b.id, b.title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2;
```

`STRING_AGG()` is a rather recent addition to SQL Server, so it might not be available in the version you are using.